# Are the spam filters legal?

Tags: smtp, spam, spam-prevention

Quick question:

If the recipient's mail server generates the command to sender:

`250 message accepted for delivery`

but for some reasons (series of spam filters) doesn't deliver it to INBOX, instead deletes or puts it in "junk' or 'spam' folders, is it a violation of any SMTP, RFC or other messaging exchange rules?

So, how far the legal is use of spam and other filters, after the agreement above (250...) is made with sender

are there any resources where it is clearly indicated or regulated?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not lawyers, and cannot say **ANYTHING** useful about the (il)legality of anything.

Comment: You were asking "are spam filters legal".  That's almost the same as asking if AdBlock is legal or if throwing away flyers that kids put in your car window is legal.  Think about it

Answer (score 0):

From an SMTP RFC-compliance point of view, it is perfectly legal to accept the email first, then cancel the delivery or re-route the email, simply because SMTP is not concerned with these latter actions. SMTP is a transmission protocol with the sole focus on transmission only. As such, it does not and cannot make any guarantees as to what happens to the email once it has been transmitted.

If the filtering happens during transmission, you can reasonably expect an 550-type code, though. [RFC2821](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2821.txt) 7.7 says:

> [...] When mail is rejected for these or other policy reasons, a 550 code SHOULD be used in response to EHLO, MAIL, or RCPT as appropriate.

Note that in RFC terminology, "SHOULD" indicates a desired, but optional feature, so this is "soft" requirement.

A harder requirement is made by [RFC2821](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2821.txt) 6.1:

> When the receiver-SMTP accepts a piece of mail (by sending a "250 OK"
>   message in response to DATA), it is accepting responsibility for
>   delivering or relaying the message. [...] If there is a delivery
>   failure after acceptance of a message, the receiver-SMTP MUST
>   formulate and mail a notification message."

This mandates a DSN to be sent in case the email cannot be delivered. However, this also explicitly allows for delivery failures (such as those due to email filtering) to happen after accepting the email.

Comment: `However, this also explicitly allows for delivery failures (such as those due to email filtering) to happen after accepting the email.`

Please, could you indicate where it is explicitly allowed in RFC2821 6.1

Comment: @cmpt: I was referring to this specifically: `If there is a delivery failure after acceptance of a message`. The only way this condition can be true is if we allow for a delivery failure that occurs after the message was accepted. If you mean to argue whether this is explicit or implicit, by all means. It can also be argued whether this is a good practice, because it can cause nasty backscattering (even a mild case of amplification attack), but in my opinion it is still legal from a technical perspective. I can't comment on the actual legal implications, though.

Comment: I think it is not a good practice at all and well described implicitly under RFC2821 6.1. 
From the point of view of message senders and/or recipients filtering messages to junk/spam folders or even more deleting them completely without delivering to inboxes, falls to that "delivery failure" category, therefore MTA should follow RFC2821 6.1 

MTA could do whatever they want to do with the message accepted for delivery, however they MUST mail notification message to sender if they are not going to deliver it inbox

Comment: I'm with you on that, it's a poor practice -- for starters, it can cause backscattering with spam (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backscatter_(email) ), a serious problem for some. My argument is concerned with the legality, though, and I think it is a legal practice (with the restrictions discussed above) from an RFC point of view. Much like using an angle grinder at 7AM on Sunday is legal, but sure it annoys your neighbors.